# Store to HDF, can't store frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe that has a custom frequency index, like so,

```
holidays = CustomBusinessDay(holidays=[ pnd.Timestamp(d) for d in pnd.Series.from_csv(f).values])
timestamps = pnd.date_range(s, e, normalize=False, freq = holidays)
df = pnd.DataFrame(columns= ['a','b'], index= timestamps)
```

When I try to store this dataframe to hdfstore, I get an error saying "can't set attribute 'freq' in node",

```
df.to_hdf('some.h5', 'df')

End of HDF5 error back trace

Can't set attribute 'freq' in node:
 /port/axis1 (Array(144,)) ''.
```

Is there a way to store this dataframe to HDFStore

Comment: you need to store this in table format, pass ``format='table'``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff's answer is correct. I was able to use format='table' and not get the error "can't set attribute 'freq' in node"